# Check Box error in wxGlade, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, wxglade

I am trying to open a wxg file which I already designed by `wxGlade`and  modified months ago that was working very well but now the main wxg does not open and I'm facing with the following error:

[image]

Note that this `wxg` file opens on other system. I tried to change the version of `wxGlade` from 6.3 which I'm using to 6.5, 6.8 or even 7.
I tried to uninstall all `pip packages` which installed after latest modification. Packages like `numpy`, `pandas` and etc however still I have the same error.

I would appreciate for any kind of suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `wxGlade` does not find `Check list Box` component. So what you can do is: put a copy of python code of your check list box plus its libraries in a folder in the following directory,

> C:\Users\yourPCname\AppData\Roaming\ .wxglade

Then, create a folder which named `widgets`

Create a txt file within widgets with the following content:

```
check_list_box
```

Put everything inside of widgets folder. Now it should work.